# metaboxes dont save html data in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

Im using this script given here https://github.com/awshout/Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/tree/master/metaboxes

its working fine but the problem is that it doesnt save html codes/tags.When I write a test is ok but when I put any html code in normal textareas or c ustom wp_editor it doesnt save the data.

below is a part of the functions to save data do you have any idea how to get it working to save html source?
thanks

```
function save_box( $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    // verify nonce
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce_field'] ) )
        return $post_id;
    if ( ! ( in_array( $post_type, $this->page ) || wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce_field'],  'custom_meta_box_nonce_action' ) ) ) 
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
        if( $field['type'] == 'section' ) {
            $sanitizer = null;
            continue;
        }
        if( in_array( $field['type'], array( 'tax_select', 'tax_checkboxes' ) ) ) {
            // save taxonomies
            if ( isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) ) {
                $term = $_POST[$field['id']];
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term, $field['id'] );
            }
        }
        else {
            // save the rest
            $new = false;
            $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true );
            if ( isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) )
                $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
            if ( isset( $new ) && '' == $new && $old ) {
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $old );
            } elseif ( isset( $new ) && $new != $old ) {
                $sanitizer = isset( $field['sanitizer'] ) ? $field['sanitizer'] : 'sanitize_text_field';
                if ( is_array( $new ) )
                    $new = meta_box_array_map_r( 'meta_box_sanitize', $new, $sanitizer );
                else
                    $new = meta_box_sanitize( $new, $sanitizer );
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $new );
            }
        }
    } // end foreach
}
```

Comment: Generally a sanitizer removes html from text inputs. Have a look at this function: `meta_box_sanitize()` and see what it does to sanitize the text. It may be the place that's stripping the html content.

Comment: Looking at the sanitization functions of the metaboxes scripts I see that most of the sanitizers would strip html content. Which `$sanitizer` is set at update time?

Comment: thanks, yes Im checking to and trying to disable but couldnt find a solution yet.I want to disable sanitier permanently

Comment: they added possibility to use visual editor too, but its not working after saving the post it removes all html datas

Comment: near the end of your code try to set the sanitizer to something more allowing of html like this `$sanitizer = 'wp_kses_post'`. That'll allow some html to pass through. Test save the metabox again with something like a `<p>....</p>` tag or a link in it and see if it stores.

Comment: William Thankyou I tried some methods as you told me I replaced under `foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {` but its doing same problem and soesnt save as html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123145/discussion-between-william-patton-and-gazi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the default sanitize functions that are used by the metaboxes script are stripping the html content from your input.

The code below will solve that by stating you want to use a different sanitizer.

```
function save_box( $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    // verify nonce
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce_field'] ) )
        return $post_id;
    if ( ! ( in_array( $post_type, $this->page ) || wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce_field'],  'custom_meta_box_nonce_action' ) ) ) 
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
        if( $field['type'] == 'section' ) {
            $sanitizer = null;
            continue;
        }
        if( in_array( $field['type'], array( 'tax_select', 'tax_checkboxes' ) ) ) {
            // save taxonomies
            if ( isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) ) {
                $term = $_POST[$field['id']];
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term, $field['id'] );
            }
        }
        else {
            // save the rest
            $new = false;
            $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true );
            if ( isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) )
                $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
            if ( isset( $new ) && '' == $new && $old ) {
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $old );
            } elseif ( isset( $new ) && $new != $old ) {
                // the code below is commented out and replaced with a line that specifically sets the sanitizer to one that will keep some html
                //$sanitizer = isset( $field['sanitizer'] ) ? $field['sanitizer'] : 'sanitize_text_field';
                $sanitizer = 'wp_kses_post'
                if ( is_array( $new ) )
                    $new = meta_box_array_map_r( 'meta_box_sanitize', $new, $sanitizer );
                else
                    $new = meta_box_sanitize( $new, $sanitizer );
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $new );
            }
        }
    } // end foreach
}
```

Note that while this works for your situation it also means all the other metaboxes are going to go through this same sanitizer when there are better alternatives that could be used for other data types.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution.
Thank you.